# Regexp - back references, translating code from PHP to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a regular expression that works in PHP, but not the MySQL REGEXP function.

```
'(.)\1{2,}'
```

In PHP this matches any char that is repeated 2 or more times, how can I translate this to work with the MySQL function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you can't.  MySQL uses POSIX regex, which doesn't support back-references.  If you must perform such matches in MySQL, your only option is to install a UDF such as [lib_mysqludf_preg](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/).